# REACT - Error to render component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I have the code below and it not work

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text } from 'react-native';

export default class Splash extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.chars}>
          <SeparateText value='AFEW' />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class SeparateText extends Component {
  render() {
    return ({
      this.props.value.split('')
        .map(char => <Text>{char}</Text>)
    });
  }
}
```

In execution, the server shows the error below:

[image]

My final objective is do somethink like this:

[image]

And I do it! Using the code below I do what I am trying do, but I need some code to show that screen using map and react. I try from many forms, but unsucessfull.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text } from 'react-native';

export default class Splash extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.splashChars}>
          <SplashChar value='A' />
          <SplashChar value='F' />
          <SplashChar value='E' />
          <SplashChar value='W' />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.splashText}>
          <Text></Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class SplashChar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Text style={styles.splashChar}>{this.props.value}</Text>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing to enclose the `JSX` inside of the `View`.

```
class SeparateText extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {this
          .props
          .value
          .split('')
          .map(char => <Text>{char}</Text>)
        }
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: nice.glad to help you

Comment: Question: the app make 4 views or 1 views with 4 texts?

Comment: `views` is for Layout and does not mean the view that we say for screen or browser.https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html. Each View  create separate layout container.For 4 there is 4 Layout conatainer

Answer (score 2):

You need a root enclose tag.

```
return (
   <View>{this.props.value.split('').map(char => <Text>{char}</Text>)</View>
);
```

Comment: My app not recognize the <div>, maybe I need import something

Comment: Well `View`, my bad.

Comment: You need to close the View tag.

Comment: @JulienD Thx :)